# Cannot change number in array into one I want

Tags: c

I have little problem here. Ever since I used srand command I no longer get output I want.
I have to create program that will create array not matter how long.. I chose 5. Then it has to create random numbers into it and 5th number in it has to be 0 and then it has to count all five numbers together. I was sucessful and I did even use some printfs to check if arr[5] is zero. It is. In output I receieve this: 5random numbers (that ones that were created into array) 0 (to check if command where i set arr[5] really set it to zero and result which only count all 5random numbers together but without changing 5th arr into 0. Any ideas why? Thanks!
Code looks like this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
        main()
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            int result,i;
            int arr[5];
            for (i=0;i<5;i++)

            {
                arr[i] = rand() % 10+1;
                printf("%d ",arr[i]);
            }

        arr[5]=0;
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d\n",arr[5]);
        i=0;

        for(;i<5;i++)
        {
            result +=arr[i];
        }

        printf("%d\n",result);
        printf("%d\n",arr[5]);

        }
```

Comment: `arr[5]` is out of the bounds of the array.

Comment: a decent compiler should warn you when using static values as indices

Comment: Please note that `result +=arr[i];` is *undefined behaviour* because you are using an *uninitialised variable* and the compiler should have warned you about that.

Comment: Don't change the posted code in response to comments except to clarify or format. Rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration `int arr[5]` gives an array with five elements numbered from 0 to 4 inclusive. Accessing the 6th element, `arr[5]`, is undefined.

If you want five elements and a "sentinel" (the zero marker), you could define `arr` as

```
int arr[6];
```

You should probably also initialize `result` to 0 otherwise its value is undefined since it's a local variable (in fact, the meaning of the whole program is, strictly speaking, undefined in this case).

Comment: How can I solve it then? Thanks

Comment: Solved. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Don't forget to click the green tick ;-)

Comment: @Fredrik I am learning this into class. Sorry I am just simple student asking for some help. I wouldn´t get this without help from tbrk. Now I learned from my mistake and will not do it anymore thanks to this.

Comment: @DušoMorháč: Good luck with your studies.